# Restore backup in aerospike

Tags: backup, restore, key-value-store, aerospike

I am trying to restore a backup from aerospike and I get this error:

```
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [INF] [20675] Starting restore to 127.0.0.1:3000 (bins: [all], sets: [all]) from backup.asb
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [INF] [20675] Processing 1 node(s)
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [INF] [20675] Restoring backup.asb
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [INF] [20675] Opened backup file backup.asb
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [ERR] [20675] Invalid version line in backup file backup.asb
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [ERR] [20675] 0000 32 30 31 36 2d 30 31 2d 32 36 20 31 00          2016-01-26 1.
2016-01-26 21:55:47 GMT [ERR] [20675] Error while opening shared backup file
2016-01-26 21:55:48 GMT [INF] [20693] 0 UDF file(s), 0 secondary index(es), 0 record(s) (0 KiB/s, 0 rec/s, 0 B/rec, backed off: 0)
2016-01-26 21:55:48 GMT [INF] [20693] Expired 0 : skipped 0 : inserted 0 : failed 0 (existed 0, fresher 0)
```

How to fix this?

Both backup and restore servers have the same version of aerospike (Aerospike Community Edition build 3.7.2)

**Here is the backup file first 42 lines:**

```
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] Starting 100% backup of 127.0.0.1:3000 (namespace: test, set: [all], bins: [all]) to [stdout]
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:415][as_cluster_seed_nodes] Add node BB90600F00A0142 127.0.0.1:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:475][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Duplicate node found BB90600F00A0142 127.0.0.1:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB91B00F00A0142 10.240.0.27:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB90500F00A0142 10.240.0.5:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB90D00F00A0142 10.240.0.13:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB90E00F00A0142 10.240.0.14:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB91700F00A0142 10.240.0.23:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:483][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Add node BB91800F00A0142 10.240.0.24:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:475][as_cluster_find_nodes_to_add] Duplicate node found BB90600F00A0142 127.0.0.1:3000
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] Processing 7 node(s)
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] Node ID             Objects        Replication
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB90600F00A0142     5897565        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB91B00F00A0142     5957713        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB90500F00A0142     5956161        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB90D00F00A0142     5955580        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB90E00F00A0142     5879393        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB91700F00A0142     5923271        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] BB91800F00A0142     5936997        3
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23418] Namespace contains 13835560 record(s)
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23453] Starting backup for node BB90600F00A0142
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23453] No secondary indexes
2016-01-26 15:54:18 GMT [INF] [23453] Backing up 0 UDF file(s)
Version 3.1
# namespace test
# first-file
+ k B 8 ADhSgg==
+ n test
+ d GmBtCbKAyOCJkFjeYld+6JOvLEU=
+ s linksd
+ g 1
+ t 0
+ b 1
- B value 8 AAibxA==
+ k B 8 AGJkEA==
+ n test
+ d GqDqbia17QaG5dEpmyBcTGv5JiI=
+ s index
+ g 133
+ t 0
+ b 1
```

Comment: I just did a quick test with 3.7.2 and saw the same version information, the restore seemed to go through fine.  Is it possible to re-generate the backup file to see if there was a minor corruption?

Comment: Hi Daniel, talking with colleagues, it would be great if we could know the command you used to take the problem backup and if you saw this problem in other backup files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First few lines, till the line you see "Version 3.1" is not valid backup.

> ....backup of 127.0.0.1:3000 (namespace: test, set: [all], bins:
>   [all]) to **[stdout]**

Based on the first line that you shared, seems you are using 'stdout' as your output filename. This will capture all the output of the backup command where it prints some runtime information also. This is confusing the restore comamnd as the backup file is not in expected format.

So, please do not redirect stdout to the backup file. If you want to capture the stdout of the backup command, you can redirect it to a file different than the backup file.

Comment: you are right. The problem happened because I used nohup command.